# Cross checking lists and dropping points that do not belong

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list of data that I would like to cross examine with a "correct" list of values and pick out the correct values.

For example:

```
dataCorrect={{387.615, 25791.5}, {388.861, 25708.8}, {411.116, 24317.1}, {441.734, 22631.7}, {442.573, 22588.8}, {455.528, 21946.4}, {459.317, 21765.3}}

data={{387.593, 35.67}, {388.841, 17.369}, {404.644, 18.1776}, {411.065, 22.952}, {419.926, 20.136}, {435.764, 49.776}, {440.713, 22.916}, {442.976, 16.657}, {447.321, 20.922}, {450.017, 24.372}, {455.409, 982.36}, {459.191, 589.4}}
```

`dataCorrect` is {pos, energy} from literature, while `data` is {pos, intensity} but has false points, such as '{404.644, 18.1776}'.

My goal is to be able to use the `dataCorrect` positions with an integrated uncertainty (+/- 0.5 for example) to select points close to the true positions.
Resulting in the following while dropping false points.

{data position, data intensity, matching energy}

```
dataFiltered={{387.593, 35.67, 25791.5}, {388.841, 17.369, 25708.8}, {411.065, 22.952, 24317.1}, {440.713, 22.916, 22631.7}, {442.976, 16.657, 22588.8},{455.409, 982.36, 21946.4}, {459.191, 589.4, 21765.3}}
```

Thank you

Comment: Define "false points."

Comment: They are points that are taken from a large, noisy set of data. I use `FindPeaks[importdata[[All, 2]], 5, .06, 15]` which does a decent job but will select points that are not florescence, just noise.

Comment: You need a crisp, unambiguous mathematical definition.  Otherwise there is no way we can help you.

Comment: There's no way to select points from one list that are within a certain range from point on another list -dropping those that aren't?

Comment: (t = #;Select[First/@data,t-.5<=#<=t+.5&])&/@(First/@dataCorrect)    this will return the points you want. One point is out of */- 0.5 and thats why not displayed. rest is list manipulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nearest` should do a good job for large datasets.

```
{posCorrect, intCorrect} = Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray[dataCorrect]];
{p, en} = Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray[data]];
δ = 0.5;(*tolereance*)

idx = Nearest[posCorrect -> "Index", p, {1, δ}]
```

> {{1}, {2}, {}, {3}, {}, {}, {}, {5}, {}, {}, {6}, {7}}

For each element if the list `p`, this finds the index of the closest element in `pos` of distance less than `δ`, if available.

```
goodidx = Flatten[Position[idx, _?(Length[#] > 0 &), 1]]
```

> {1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 12}

These are the indices of the positions in `p` that seem to be okay.

```
dataFiltered = Transpose[{p[[goodidx]], en[[goodidx]], intCorrect[[Flatten[idx]]]}]
```

> {{387.593, 35.67, 25791.5}, {388.841, 17.369, 25708.8}, {411.065, 
>     22.952, 24317.1}, {442.976, 16.657, 22588.8}, {455.409, 982.36, 
>     21946.4}, {459.191, 589.4, 21765.3}}

I use `` Developer`ToPackedArray `` to pack the input data for more efficient processing. With these small input datasets, that does not matter, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Join @@ Table[
   If[Abs[j[[1]] - k[[1]]] <= 0.5, Append[k, j[[2]]]],
   {j, dataCorrect},
   {k, data}
   ] // DeleteCases[#, Null] &
```

> {{387.593, 35.67, 25791.5}, {388.841, 17.369, 25708.8}, {411.065, 
>     22.952, 24317.1}, {442.976, 16.657, 22588.8}, {455.409, 982.36, 
>     21946.4}, {459.191, 589.4, 21765.3}}

And as was pointed out in the comments, the point `{440.713, 22.916, 22631.7}` does not meet the criterion of being within 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
s=(t=#;Select[First/@data,t-.5<=#<=t+.5&])&/@(First/@dataCorrect);
Quiet@Table[
Join[data[[First@(# & @@ 
    Position[data, First@s[[k]]])]], {dataCorrect[[k]][[2]]}], {k,
Length@dataCorrect}]
```